# How to count continuous numbers in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Numpy one-dimensional array of 1 and 0. for e.g

```
a = np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])
```

I want to count the continuous 0s and 1s in the array and output something like this

```
[1,3,7,1,1,2,3,2,2]
```

What I do atm is

```
np.diff(np.where(np.abs(np.diff(a)) == 1)[0])
```

and it outputs

```
array([3, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2])
```

as you can see it is missing the first count 1.

I've tried `np.split` and then get the sizes of each segments but it does not seem to be optimistic.

Is there more elegant "pythonic" solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach -

```
np.diff(np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a))+1,a.size])
```

Sample run -

```
In [208]: a = np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])

In [209]: np.diff(np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a))+1,a.size])
Out[209]: array([1, 3, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2])
```

Faster one with `boolean` concatenation -

```
np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate(([True], a[1:]!= a[:-1], [True] ))))
```

**Runtime test**

For the setup, let's create a bigger dataset with islands of `0s` and `1s` and for a fair benchmarking as with the given sample, let's have the island lengths vary between `1` and `7` -

```
In [257]: n = 100000 # thus would create 100000 pair of islands

In [258]: a = np.repeat(np.arange(n)%2, np.random.randint(1,7,(n)))

# Approach #1 proposed in this post
In [259]: %timeit np.diff(np.r_[0,np.flatnonzero(np.diff(a))+1,a.size])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.13 ms per loop

# Approach #2 proposed in this post
In [260]: %timeit np.diff(np.flatnonzero(np.concatenate(([True], a[1:]!= a[:-1], [True] ))))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.21 ms per loop

# @Vineet Jain's soln    
In [261]: %timeit [ sum(1 for i in g) for k,g in groupby(a)]
10 loops, best of 3: 61.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have a suggestion how I could adapt your code such that I could do this row-wise on a 2D numpy array?

Answer (score 5):

Using `groupby` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import groupby
a = np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])
grouped_a = [ sum(1 for i in g) for k,g in groupby(a)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar method to yours, just that this code finds the first and the last count separately. The answer is detailed in the code below:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0])
print(f'a: {a}')

diff_a = np.diff(a)
print(f'diff_a: {diff_a}')

non_zero_pos_arr = np.where(diff_a != 0)[0]
print(f'Array of positions where non zero elements are present in diff_a array: {non_zero_pos_arr}')

diff_non_zero_pos_arr = np.diff(non_zero_pos_arr)
print(f'Result Array except for first and last element: {diff_non_zero_pos_arr}')

ans_first_ele = non_zero_pos_arr[0] + 1

ans_last_ele = len(diff_a) - non_zero_pos_arr[-1]

ans = np.array([], dtype=np.int8)
ans = np.append(ans, ans_first_ele)
ans = np.append(ans, diff_non_zero_pos_arr)
ans = np.append(ans, ans_last_ele)

print(f'Result Array: {ans}')
```

Output:

```
a: [0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0]
diff_a: [ 1  0  0 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 -1  1  0 -1  0  0  1  0 -1  0]
Array of positions where non zero elements are present in diff_a array: 
 [ 0  3 10 11 12 14 17 19]
Result Array except for first and last element: [3 7 1 1 2 3 2]
Result Array: [1 3 7 1 1 2 3 2 2]
```